# mongodb adding field by checking document with id

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have Job collection like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6aecd49bcdb5d4ae64ae5d"),
    "jobID" : "1",
    "jobStatus" : "active",
    "jobEndsDate" : ISODate("2018-08-15T23:59:59.014Z")
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6aed179bcdb5d4ae64ae99"),
    "jobID" : "2",
    "jobStatus" : "active",
    "jobEndsDate" : ISODate("2018-08-15T23:59:59.014Z")
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6aed2e9bcdb5d4ae64aeb8"),
    "jobID" : "3",
    "jobStatus" : "active",
    "jobEndsDate" : ISODate("2018-08-15T23:59:59.014Z")
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6aed419bcdb5d4ae64aec0"),
    "jobID" : "4",
    "jobStatus" : "expired",
    "jobEndsDate" : ISODate("2018-08-01T23:59:59.014Z")
}
```

and User collection like this

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5b63047d2eef2646f3ad5887"),
"userID" : "1",
"appliedJobIds":["1","2"]
```

I want all the job douctments which are applied by userID:"1".For applied jobs add one field as "jobStatus":"applied"(not updating,by using $addField) and for remaining which are not expired as jobStatus":"not applied" by passing userID in query.

output should be like this:

OUTPUT:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5b6979339bcdb5d4ae64498f"),
"jobID" : "1"
"jobStatus" : "active"
"jobEndsDate" : ISODate("2018-08-15T23:59:59.014Z"),
"jobApplyStatus":"applied"

 "_id" : ObjectId("5b6979339bcdb5d4ae64498g"),
 "jobID" : "2"
"jobStatus" : "active"
"jobEndsDate" : ISODate("2018-08-15T23:59:59.014Z"),
"jobApplyStatus":"applied"

"_id" : ObjectId("5b6979339bcdb5d4ae64498h"),
 "jobID" : "3"
"jobStatus" : "active"
"jobEndsDate" : ISODate("2018-08-15T23:59:59.014Z"),
"jobApplyStatus":"not applied"
```

please help me i am not understanding how to do.
Thank you

Comment: Can you add the expected json output to the post ?

Comment: Why is there two keys with the same name in output json `"jobStatus" : "active"` and `"jobStatus":"applied"`

Comment: @nithin - Let's get rid of the "bro" stuff. This isn't a guys-only hangout for you and your friends; it's a q&a site for everyone.

Comment: yes agree. Please stop assuming the people you are talking to are men and men that enjoy being called "bro"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below pipeline in 3.6.

[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) with pipeline to join the user collection to job collection.

[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) with [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) to compare the applied jobs against each job id in the job collection and output a new field o the existing job.

[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) to promote all the jobs to the top level.

```
db.User.aggregate([
{"$match":{"userID":"1"}},
{"$lookup":{
  "from":"Job",
  "let":{"appliedJobIds":"$appliedJobIds"},
  "pipeline":[
    {"$match":{"jobStatus":"active"}},
    {"$addFields":{
      "jobApplyStatus":{"$cond":[{"$in":["$jobID","$$appliedJobIds"]},"applied","not applied"]}
    }}
  ],
  "as":"jobs"
}},
{"$unwind":"$jobs"},
{"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$jobs"}}
])
```